# Update slider and textbox with year\month count using radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

Here is my current setup.

1. 2 radio button to select either year or month
2. 2 sliders, one for year and another one for month
3. Textbox which will display value of the slider

using onclick radio function, I am displaying only one slider depends upon the year\month selection.

when I change option between year and month, I would like to update the slider and textbox value accordingly. For example, if the year slider is on year 15 and when I change radio button to month, the slider should move to 180 (15*12) and textbox should update as 180.
As of now, I am able to display\hide the slider depends on the radio selection and update the textbox with slider value. But this value is not getting converted between year and month.

How can I achieve this ?

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/vvemxcL3/

Below is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="inputQ">
  <div class="InputQuest">Loan Tenure</div>
  <div><input id="tentext" class="textbox"></div>

   <div class="switch-field">
      <div class="switch-title"></div>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yr</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" />
      <label for="switch_right">Mo</label>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="MarkWrap1" id="MarkWrap1">  
<div id="tenslidery" class="tenslidery"></div>


    <div class="T">0</div>
    <div class="T">5</div>
    <div class="T">10</div>
    <div class="T">15</div>
    <div class="T">20</div>
    <div class="T">25</div>
    <div class="T">30</div>
  </div>

 <div class="MarkWrap2" id="MarkWrap2"> 
<div id="tensliderm" class="tensliderm"></div>


    <div class="Tm">0</div>
    <div class="Tm">60</div>
    <div class="Tm">120</div>
    <div class="Tm">180</div>
    <div class="Tm">240</div>
    <div class="Tm">300</div>
    <div class="Tm">360</div>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( "#tentext" ).val( "20");
$("#tenslidery").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 30 ,
        value: 20,
        step: .1,
        animate: true,
        range:'min',
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#tentext" ).val( ui.value );
    }



    });



$("#tentext").on("keyup",function(e){

     $("#tenslidery").slider("value",this.value);
});

$("#tensliderm").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        value: 240,
        step: 1,
        animate: true,
        range:'min',
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#tentext" ).val( ui.value );
    }



    });



$("#tentext").on("keyup",function(e){

     $("#tensliderm").slider("value",this.value);
});


function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('switch_left').checked) {
        document.getElementById('MarkWrap1').style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById('MarkWrap2').style.display = 'none';


    }
    else if (document.getElementById('switch_right').checked) {


    document.getElementById('MarkWrap2').style.display = 'flex';
         document.getElementById('MarkWrap1').style.display = 'none';

}
}
```

CSS:

```
.tenslidery {
   height:8px;
  flex-basis:100%;
  margin:0 calc((100% / 7) / 2);
}

.T {
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family:verdana;
  margin-top:15px;
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.T:before {
   content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:15px;
  bottom:100%;
  width:1px;
  left:calc(50% - 1px);
  background:#c5c5c5;
}

.MarkWrap1 {
  width:83%; /*Adjust this to adjust the width*/
  margin: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;


}

.Tm {
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family:verdana;
  margin-top:15px;
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.Tm:before {
   content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:15px;
  bottom:100%;
  width:1px;
  left:calc(50% - 1px);
  background:#c5c5c5;
}

.MarkWrap2 {
  width:83%; /*Adjust this to adjust the width*/
  margin: auto;
  display:none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;


}

.tensliderm {
   height:8px;
  flex-basis:100%;
  margin:0 calc((100% / 7) / 2);
}

.switch-field {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;

    overflow: hidden;

    width:auto;
}



.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  float: left;
}

label[for=switch_right]
{


  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:4px;
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

}

label[for=switch_left]
{


  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;



}



.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
height:25.4px;
line-height:1.4;
padding:2px;
   cursor: pointer;
}


.switch-field label switch-right ( background:red;)
.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: deeppink;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply explicitly calculate the the values and submit to both slider and input box, should solve your problem

```
function yesnoCheck() {
  var markWrap1 = $('#MarkWrap1');
  var markWrap2 = $('#MarkWrap2');
  var text = $('#tentext');
  var value;
  if ($('#switch_left').is(':checked')) {
    markWrap1.css('display', 'flex');
    markWrap2.css('display', 'none');
    value = +$('#tensliderm').slider("option", "value") / 12;
    text.val(String(value));
    $('#tenslidery').slider('value', value);
  } else if ($('#switch_right').is(':checked')) {
    markWrap2.css('display', 'flex');
    markWrap1.css('display', 'none');
    value = +$('#tenslidery').slider("option", "value") * 12;
    text.val(String(value));
    $('#tensliderm').slider('value', value);
  }
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/kevinkassimo/ayhenhL5/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just as a tidy up and to add readability...

This will keep both sliders and the input in sync at all times, so if you need to get any current value elsewhere, it will be correct.

```
var yearVal;
var monthVal;
var yearSelected;

configure();

function updateVal(val) {
  yearVal = yearSelected ? val : val / 12;
  monthVal = yearSelected ? val * 12 : val;
}

function switchSliders() {
  document.getElementById('MarkWrap1').style.display = yearSelected ? 'flex' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('MarkWrap2').style.display = yearSelected ? 'none' : 'flex';
}

function updateSliders() {
  $("#tenslidery").slider("value", yearVal);
  $("#tensliderm").slider("value", monthVal);
}

function updateTenure() {
  $("#tentext").val(yearSelected ? yearVal : monthVal);
}

function yesnoCheck() {
  yearSelected = document.getElementById('switch_left').checked;
  updateTenure();
  switchSliders();
  updateSliders();
}

function configure() {
  $("#tenslidery").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 30,
    value: 0,
    step: .1,
    animate: true,
    range: 'min',
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      updateVal(ui.value);
      $("#tentext").val(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $("#tensliderm").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    value: 0,
    step: 1,
    animate: true,
    range: 'min',
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      updateVal(ui.value);
      $("#tentext").val(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $("#tentext").on("keyup", function (e) {
    updateVal(Number(this.value));
    updateSliders();
  });

  yearVal = 20;
  monthVal = yearVal * 12;
  yearSelected = true;
  $("#tentext").val(yearVal);
  updateSliders();
}
```